# In PostgreSQL, do PL/pgSQL and SQL have different CREATE FUNCTION commands?

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

In PostgreSQL document, the commands to create a PL/pgSQL function and to create a SQL function seem very similar but with differences:

> Functions written in PL/pgSQL are defined to the server by executing
>   CREATE FUNCTION commands. Such a command would normally look like,
>   say,
>
> ```
> CREATE FUNCTION somefunc(integer, text) RETURNS integer
> AS 'function body text'
> LANGUAGE plpgsql;
> ```
>
> The function body is simply a string literal so far as  CREATE
>   FUNCTION  is concerned. It is often helpful to use dollar quoting (see
>   Section 4.1.2.4) to write the function body, rather than the normal
>   single quote syntax. Without dollar quoting, any single quotes or
>   backslashes in the function body must be escaped by doubling them.
>   Almost all the examples in this chapter use dollar-quoted literals for
>   their function bodies. PL/pgSQL is a block-structured language. The
>   complete text of a function body must be a block. A block is defined
>   as:
>
> ```
> [ <<label>> ]
> [ DECLARE
>     declarations ]
> BEGIN
>     statements
> END [ label ];
> ```

In the list of SQL commands:

```
CREATE [ OR REPLACE ] FUNCTION
    name ( [ [ argmode ] [ argname ] argtype [ { DEFAULT |
 = } default_expr ] [, ...] ] )
    [ RETURNS rettype
      | RETURNS TABLE ( column_name column_type [, ...] ) ]
  { LANGUAGE lang_name
    | TRANSFORM { FOR TYPE type_name } [, ... ]
    | WINDOW
    | IMMUTABLE | STABLE | VOLATILE | [ NOT ] LEAKPROOF
    | CALLED ON NULL INPUT | RETURNS NULL ON NULL INPUT | STRICT
    | [ EXTERNAL ] SECURITY INVOKER | [ EXTERNAL ] SECURITY DEFINER
    | PARALLEL { UNSAFE | RESTRICTED | SAFE }
    | COST execution_cost
    | ROWS result_rows
    | SET configuration_parameter { TO value | = value | FROM
 CURRENT }
    | AS 'definition'
    | AS 'obj_file', 'link_symbol'
  } ...
    [ WITH ( attribute [, ...] ) ]
```

For example, we can specify a language

- by `LANGUAGE ...` at the end in the PL/pgSQL command and
- by `LANGUAGE lang_name` in the SQL command.

Are they really two different commands? Or are they  the same command?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cited definition of [CREATE FUNCTION](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createfunction.html) is common for all languages:

> *lang_name*
>
> The name of the language that the function is implemented in. It can be sql, c, internal, or the name of a user-defined procedural language, e.g. plpgsql.

Comment: Thanks. Does `lang_name` only  specify which language the function body is written in? Does it affect the signature of the function (parameter and return of the function)?

Comment: *lang_name* only specify which language the function body is written in and does not affect *the signature.*